# convert byte[] to pdf and return it

Tags: pdf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

How to write memory stream into pdf and export it? I am working in .net core 2.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult getPdfDate(int id)
{
   ApplicationDbContext docs = new ApplicationDbContext();
   var data = docs.UsersDocs.FindAsync(id);       
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data.Result.doc);
}
```

Comment: One of the things you need to do is show you've done some research. ".net core write stream to PDF" is a good start. What is specific to your problem and code that none of these references apply?

Comment: As a side note (and it's only a small one), you're calling Asynchronous code (`docs.UserDocs.FindAsync(id)`) synchronously (`data.Result.doc`). This will lock the executing thread until FindAsync completes and can be bad for performance. Just something to be aware of for once you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your `doc` property is a `byte[]` that is already a "PDF". As a result, you simply dump the bytes with the appropriate mime-type:

```
var data = await docs.UsersDocs.FindAsync(id);
return File(data.doc, "application/pdf");
```

As @JamieTaylor pointed out, you need to await your async call. Otherwise, you'll deadlock the thread. Also, don't new up your context in your action. Register it with your services in `ConfigureServices` in `StartUp` and then inject it into your controller:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public FooController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```